# Python: Combining string and lists

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

I have a list of counters

```
counters = ['76195087', '963301809', '830123644', '60989448', '0', '0', '76195087', '4006066839', '390361581', '101817210', '0', '0']
```

and I would like to create a string using some of these counters....

```
cmd = 'my_command' + counters[0:1]
```

But I find that I am unable to concatenate strings and lists.

What I must have at the end is a string that looks like this:

```
my_command 76195087
```

How do I get these numbers out of their list and get them to behave like strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `join` strings in a list with, well, [`join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
cmd = 'my_command' + ''.join(counters[:1])
```

**But you shouldn't construct a command like that in the first place** and give it to `os.popen` or `os.system`. Instead, use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, which handles the internals (and escapes problematic values):

```
import subprocess
# You may want to set some options in the following line ...
p = subprocess.Popen(['my_command'] + counters[:1])
p.communicate()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a single element of the list, just index that element:

```
cmd = 'my_command ' + counters[0]
```

If you want to join several elements, use the 'join()' method of strings:

```
cmd = 'my_command ' + " ".join(counters[0:2]) # add spaces between elements
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to append a single counter, you can use

```
"my_command " + counters[0]
```

or

```
"%s %s" % (command, counters[0])
```

where `command` is a variable containing the command as a string.  If you want to append more than one counter, `' '.join()` is your friend:

```
>>> ' '.join([command] + counters[:3])
'my_command 76195087 963301809 830123644'
```

Comment: are the double quotes significant?  when I use single quotes I get the following message:  TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: also... I will need to use several of the counters as arguments in the command.  How do I bring in several counters?  + counters[0] + counters[3], etc?

Comment: @TheWellington The double quotes are the same as single quotes, and [I doubt you are using the exact code above](http://ideone.com/uyE18).

Answer (score 1):

You have to access an *element* of the list, not *sublists* of the list, like this:

```
cmd = 'my_command' + counters[0]
```

Since I guess you're interested in using all the counters at some point, use a variable to store the index you're currently using, and increment it where you see fit (possibly inside a loop)

```
idx = 0
cmd1 = 'my_command' + counters[idx]
idx += 1
cmd2 = 'my_command' + counters[idx]
```

Of course, being careful of not incrementing the index variable beyond the size of the list.